# Make comparison "For ” some indicators

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions, difference, prepositional-phrases

For example, I want to express:

> I made a comparison between two companies "for" indicators like growth rate, profitability

I am wondering what is the correct preposition to use. Should I say "for indicators" or "in indicators" or there are better expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "for indicators":

> I did something **for** something

"in indicators" isn't really idiomatic especially when you aren't specifically doing something **in** something else.